# Use HTML5 Geolocation API to store current_user_position in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

I am currently using the html5 geolocation api to get the current user location(lat lng), geocode it with the geocoder gem and attache the data to a post a user has written. These posts are only visible within a certain range of the stored location. Now my question. Is it possible to get a user's location, look for posts that are accessible at this location and throw out the right content directly on the page load? Maybe a combination of javascript ajax and rails? I have no clue. My only idea is to use the javascript to store the location data in a search field and the user have to submit this field and than he gets the right content. But I want this done complete in background by page load. Any ideas? You would help me a lot, guys :)

Comment: How specific does the location need to be? If it's displaying content by country then GeoIP is the way to go.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. But this doesn't right answer my question^^ Getting the user position is no problem. It's all about the background process on page load. I don't know how to extract the variables of a Javascript to use them in my erb code to show the right content on the page

Comment: your question is too verbose/ambiguous for us to help you, maybe provide us with some code to look @ and how far you are into getting these co-ordinates.

Comment: i am not able to share any code because of my client's agreement. but again. i use javascript to get the position of a user and storing this position in a user's post is no problem too. the only problem i have is the page load. I want to publish the right position based content for each user on first visit via ajax and not load the page -> get the user position and than load another page via button to get the right content. so maybe store the javascript position in a user's session and make it accesible via some code. but i don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I use a callback to post the user's position back to Rails via ajax. Rails stores the position (if necessary), returns results based on the position, and responds with the results.

- Initial request -> empty page
- client resolves position
- callback posts coordinates to server via ajax
- ???
- server responds with content
- update page

ERb is rendered long before client side Javascript even runs. Client-derived data like geo position must be posted back to the server.

Comment: this really much sounds like a method I want to give a try to. Could you send me an example code for this? would be awesome :)